# React: Pattern for Parent Initiated fetch of Child data?

Tags: reactjs

For performance reasons I have a child element whose data is stored in its state and only its state (instead of being passed up the hierarchal chain using callbacks passed in props).

There then comes a time where an action in the parent element dictates that I now need that data, what is the correct pattern for fetching it in the child?

Do I use refs and call a child.fetchData() method via a saved reference?

Do I change a prop flag causing the child to call a prop callback with the data?

Comment: You say "the child to call a prop callback with the data", but you said "data is stored in its state and only its state (instead of being passed up the hierarchal chain using callbacks passed in props)" ... so do you need this data in the parent or not?

Comment: I need the data in the parent at a certain time, but for performance reasons I cannot have the child's state constantly updating itself and its parent with every change. So I'm looking for a pattern where the parent can 'fetch' the childs data when it needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would

1. store the data outside of both your parent and your child (an example of this could be a redux store, or some global "cache" object)
2. create a shared method of fetching said data (one example of this could be a redux action)
3. make sure you're storing that data immutably, so that you can...
4. check if the fetched data had changed in `shouldComponentUpdate()` of the parent and child, to combat your performance reservations